# Prepared Statement Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, prepared-statement, pivot-table

There are 3 tables in a sales database: `orders(order_id, user_id, item_id, quantity, date), users(user_id, name, discount_percent) and items(item_id, name, type, price)`. I'm trying to generate a report for the monthly profit by user grouped by days that must look this (snippet):

```
|-------user--------|----------day_1--------|---------day_2---------|---------day_3---------| etc. |

|-user_name_1-|-sum_of_expenses-|-sum_of_expenses-|-sum_of_expenses-| etc. |

|-user_name_2-|-sum_of_expenses-|-sum_of_expenses-|-sum_of_expenses-| etc. |
```

I used the following prepared statement to achieve this:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(DATE(orders.date) = \'', 
                DATE(orders.date),
                '\', orders.quantity * items.price * (1 - users.discount_percent / 100), 0)) AS ',
                DATE(orders.date))
        ORDER BY DATE(orders.date))
INTO @sql FROM 
    orders;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT users.name, ', @sql, ' FROM 
    users
        INNER JOIN
    orders ON users.user_id = orders.user_id
        INNER JOIN
    items ON orders.item_id = items.item_id
GROUP BY users.name
ORDER BY users.user_id');

PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

For some reason it gives me a warning:

```
1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1260 Row 8 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()
```

And then an error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2015-01-01,SUM(IF(DATE(orders.date) = '2015-01-02', orders.quantity * items.pric' at line 1
```

I think this has something to do with the format of the date or the quotes, but everything I type in order to fix it fails.

Also I'm trying to figure out how to implement this complex statement via php's mysqli prepare() method.

Comment: I don't think that `SELECT ... INTO` a variable will work directly on MySQL.  But why are you overwriting `@sql` right after assigning something to it?

Answer (score 2):

For the first warning, MySql group_concat function is limited by default to 1024.

You can increase the limit before your query by using:

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 32000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have a syntax error in SQL, it's much easier to find the problem by looking at the final SQL that was generated—*not* the code used to generate the SQL.

In this case, I think you'll find that the column alias you're defining lacks quotes:

```
SUM(IF(DATE(orders.date) = '2015-01-01', 
       orders.quantity * items.price * (1 - users.discount_percent / 100), 
       0)
) AS 2015-01-01
```

That's not a legal column alias. You must put quotes around it.

I recommend you use the QUOTE() function as you create your prepared SQL statement:

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM(IF(DATE(orders.date) = ', 
            QUOTE(DATE(orders.date)),
            ', orders.quantity * items.price * (1 - users.discount_percent / 100), 0)) AS ',
            QUOTE(DATE(orders.date)))
    ORDER BY DATE(orders.date))
INTO @sql FROM 
orders;
```